# Enable https between Nginx and Payara (private network)

Tags: nginx, ssl, payara

I have obtained certificate using certbot for nginx (public ip) which is subdomain.domain.com and it works just fine, but when I try to access payara admin throught nginx (subdomain.domain.com:4848 redirects to private ip of payara that sits deeper inside vpc) it gives me a warning that https connection is not secured.

I assume I need install certificate the same way I did for nginx but this time for payara, but payara is in the private network and it doesn't have internal dns hostname. Do I need to generate certificate also for the same subdomain.domain.com and then use it in payara ? When I do it it says

> Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.

How do I configure secure connection between nginx (public ip) and payara (private ip) so when I access https://subdomain.domain.com:4848 connection is secure ?

```
    server {
    listen       4848 ssl;
    listen       [::]:4848 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    server_name  sub.domain.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://10.1.1.10:4848/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        client_max_body_size 0;
     }
}
```

if I access payara locally using `https://localhost:4848` it shows insecure connection and some general Oracle glassfish certificate

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve… do you want to make Payara publicly accessible through nginx? Showing your nginx config would help a lot.

Comment: yes, nginx works as proxy and redirects all requests to the payara server that is located in the private network. My question is besides configuring SSL on nginx, do I need additionally configure ssl between nginx and payara ?

Comment: Redirecting is a different thing than proxying… when proxying you do not *need* to use HTTPS; it's your decision if you want to have the traffic encrypted. Try with `proxy_pass http://10.1.1.10:4848;` if Payara serves HTTP.

Comment: I do want to encrypt communication to harden the security. If I `proxy_pass http://10.1.1.10:4848;` it won't work.

Comment: That's fine… you just have to ensure that Payara is setup correctly. Verify HTTPS setup with e.g. `curl -ki https://10.1.1.10:4848`

Comment: curl works fine, but payara (4.1.171) is not setup correctly, in the admin > server-config > network-listeners > http-listener-2 > SSL it's asking for a certificate and the one it has right now is from a different domain. How do I provision certificate for the right domain ? payara is in private network and let's encrypt won't work since port 80/443 is closed.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which certificate is configured, as nginx doesn't normally verify it ([proxy_ssl_verify](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_verify) is `off` by default).